# Can you identify this vintage Moor MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I've recently acquired this bike:

[image]

[image]

The Moor brand seems to be coming from Denmark. However, the SFMK CSCM sticker seems to be referring tot the "Suisse Motorbike and Bicycle Union".
The bike was bought in Germany.
All the components are Shimano Deore.

Does anybody has more information?

Thanks

Comment: No sorry, but excellent work including all that information.  Often the ID my bike questions don't make it to one complete line of text.

Comment: Interesting bike. Obviously built for the European market (the lights).  Thumb shifters (and hence indexed shifting) and front canti brake indicate it's not ancient.  It is a (good quality) lugged steel frame, however, and I don't know how to date that funky center-pull canti brake on the rear.  I would put it's origin date at 2000-2005, though likely that can be nailed down more accurately by checking the dates that the specific components were being manufactured.

Comment: The under the chainstay U-brake mounting was only popular in the mid to late 1980s as far as I know, cause they weren't exactly a good idea. And its got a threaded headset. So, I don't think 2000-2005 is a good estimate -- I'd estimate 1985-1990.

Comment: There's always a chance previous owners have swapped components in from other bikes as well.  But when I was trying to date a cheaper MTB with canti brakes and (basic shimano) thumb shifters I got to early 90s.

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of the bottom bracket - see if there is any information stamped there. There is often a serial number which will allow you to pin it down (particularly if someone can find a listing from Moor).

Comment: Its a nice looking rigid too.  I'd loose the kickstand (cos it looks heavy) and I'd swap the yellow wheel reflectors for clip-on white or yellow spoke reflectors, and I'd ride it.

Comment: @Batman - My 1998 Novara has a threaded headset.  Remember, it's a steel frame.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - Fair. The main reason why I think its older though is that rear brake mounting. At least in the US, we'd figured out it wasn't a good idea well before the turn of the millenium.

Comment: @Batman - Note that that isn't an "old fashioned" U center pull, but rather uses canti posts.  I think the design is fairly modern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It think it's a Swiss bike.

The top tube says Velo Sport Walpen Fiesch.

- Walpen is a [Swiss surname](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walpen) from Valais in Switzerland.
- [Fiesch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiesch) is a municipality in Valais in Switzerland.
- There is/was a Swiss bike company called Moor, which on older bikes carry this [head badge](https://www.flickr.com/photos/hugovk/26211508731/):

[image: Moor (Switzerland) bicycle head badge logo]

- I found an old German eBay listing in the [Google web cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WpSeG3X3_BcJ:www.reklametafel.net/s-anzeige/26-moor-mtb-retro-vintage-54cm-/456744407-217-3433%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) for this bike in Berlin, which doesn't give much more info, but the bike was also bought in Germany.

> [image: Moor] [image: Moor] [image: Moor] [image: Moor] [image: Moor] [image: Moor] [image: Moor]
>
> 26" MOOR MTB, Retro, Vintage 54cm. kaufen in Deutschland
>
> Preis: 100 €
>
> Details
>
> Erstellungsdatum:
>   21.04.2016
>   Anzeigennummer:
>   456744407
>   Art:
>   Herren
>   Schlagwörter:
>   26 Zoll Shimano
>
> Beschreibung
>
> Verkaufe ein sehr schoenes und originales MTB der Marke MOOR 26 Zoll, RH von 54cm,mit ,21 Gänge.komlett Shimano Deore ausstatung,Lichtanlage und Schützblech Das Fahrrad ist gebraucht aber im sehr guten Zustand,Preis 100 Euro

And of course "SFMK CSCM Service Garantie" points to Switzerland too.

Comment: That's a dead-ringer for OP's bike.  Great spotting!

Comment: Cool thanks for the information. That's actually my bicycle on this ad. Since then it has been transformed into a drop bar tourer. For some reason, I thought Moor was a Danish brand as you can see on this [thread](http://www.fam-amv.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=718).

Comment: @m0g No wonder it's a dead-ringer, should have paid more attention to bottle cage! I don't read German but don't see where in that thread it says it's Danish; although [Däniken is in Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A4niken,_Solothurn).

Comment: @Hugo true, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think Batman is correct.  1985-1990 estimate

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't disagree, but good answers need more detail, perhaps you can [edit] in some reasons why this time frame, like frame lugs, component choices, stem type, wheel size etc, or anything else you know about the brand.